# Pytorch: Understand how nn.Module class internally work

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Generally, a `nn.Module` can be inherited by a subclass as below.

```
def init_weights(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Linear:
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(m.weight)  # 

class LinearRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LinearRegression, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 1)
        self.apply(init_weights)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x
```

My 1st question is, why I can simply run the code below even my `__init__` doesn't have any positinoal arguments for `training_signals` and it looks like that `training_signals` is passed to `forward()` method. How does it work?

```
model = LinearRegression()
training_signals = torch.rand(1000,20)
model(training_signals)
```

The second question is that how does `self.apply(init_weights)` internally work? Is it executed before calling `forward` method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Q1: Why I can simply run the code below even my `__init__` doesn't have any positional arguments for `training_signals` and it looks like that `training_signals` is passed to `forward()` method. How does it work?

First, the `__init__` is called when you run this line:

```py
model = LinearRegression()
```

As you can see, you pass no parameters, and you shouldn't. The signature of your `__init__` is the same as the one of the base class (which you call when you run `super(LinearRegression, self).__init__()`). As you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/be757957bace28100e571ec7914765020be4a069/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L69), `nn.Module`'s init signature is simply `def __init__(self)` (just like yours).

Second, `model` is now an object. When you run the line below:

```py
model(training_signals)
```

You are actually calling the `__call__` method and passing `training_signals` as a positional parameter. As you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/be757957bace28100e571ec7914765020be4a069/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L522-L550), among many other things, the `__call__` method calls the `forward` method:

```py
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
```

passing all parameters (positional and named) of the `__call__` to the `forward`.

> Q2: How does `self.apply(init_weights)` internally work? Is it executed before calling forward method?

PyTorch is Open Source, so you can simply go to the source-code and check it. As you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/be757957bace28100e571ec7914765020be4a069/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L248-L288), the implementation is quite simple:

```py
def apply(self, fn):
    for module in self.children():
        module.apply(fn)
    fn(self)
    return self
```

Quoting the documentation of the function: it "*applies `fn` recursively to every submodule (as returned by `.children()`) as well as `self`*". Based on the implementation, you can also understand the requirements:

- `fn` must be a callable;
- `fn` receives as input only a `Module` object;