# how does the neural netwok definition in pytorch use pyton classes

Tags: python, class, neural-network, pytorch

in order to understand how this code works, I have written a [small reproducer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MvESndIsHOguhp_1AIaTN8u5Qi56sez/view). How does the self.hidden variable use a variable x in the forward method?

```
enter code class Network(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # Inputs to hidden layer linear transformation
    self.hidden = nn.Linear(784, 256)
    # Output layer, 10 units - one for each digit
    self.output = nn.Linear(256, 10)

    # Define sigmoid activation and softmax output 
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

def forward(self, x):
    # Pass the input tensor through each of our operations
    x = self.hidden(x)
    x = self.sigmoid(x)
    x = self.output(x)
    x = self.softmax(x)

    return x
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking... what do you mean how? It does it this way: `x = self.hidden(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood what `self.hidden = nn.Linear(784, 256)` does. You wrote that:

> `hidden` is defined as a function

but this is not true. `self.hidden` is an object of the class `nn.Linear`. And when you call `self.hidden(...)`, you are not passing arguments to `nn.Linear`; you are passing arguments to `__call__` (defined in the `nn.Linear` class).

If you want more details on that, I have expanded on how it works in PyTorch: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801221/4228275).